# Upload File From Colab to Google Drive Folder

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I want to upload a file from colab to a specific folder in my google drive. I can get the folder by using the folder id and below snippet:

```
my_folder = drive.ListFile(
        {'q': "'1QYaM1vaUvdzbdsfWbsolncz1xc2pgnpextuP' in parents"}).GetList()
```

But my question: how do I upload a file(image) to this folder? Is there a function such as

> my_folder.upload(my_file)?

So far I have seen some examples with zip files but I do not want to upload it as a zip file.

Comment: I would be interested to know how you can so  it using a zip file.

Answer (score 5):

**step(1) mount drive with colab **

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

**step(2) import shutil**

```
import shutil
```

**step 3 copy file using shutil**

```
shutil.copy("file_path","/content/drive/MyDrive/folder_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

I take from [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26644)

```
fid = '1QYaM1vaUvdzbdsfWbsolncz1xc2pgnpextuP'
f = drive.CreateFile({"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink", "id": fid}]})
f.SetContentFile( some_path )
f.Upload()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better solution is to just use the 'cp' GNU utility, in an empty cell of colab's notebook.

```
!cp sourceFileFolder/sourceFile.ext drive/MyDrive/DestFolderInGDrive/
```

Colabs run the Ubuntu OS and hence not only `cp`, but `mv`, `zip`, `unzip`, `tar`, `bzip2`, `gzip` are all available. `git`, `gcc`, `g++`, `java`, `javac`, `python` etc are available as well. For the google colab environment, once google drive is mounted, its just another folder in the local environment of colab.

For changing directories, you can use the magic command `%cd path/to/directory/absolute/or/relative`